Compile tables translated from DOCX by Pandoc
Starting with a simple .docx file containing a table:

Converted to LaTeX with vanilla Pandoc:
pandoc ./Table.docx -o Table.tex

Produces the following output:
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.3333}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.3334}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.3334}}@{}}
\toprule()
\endhead
\textbf{Heading 1} & \textbf{Heading 2} & \textbf{Heading 3} \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule()
\end{longtable}

Which doesn't compile:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> @{} >{\raggedright \arraybackslash
                                              }p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep...
l.10 ...nwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.3334}}@{}}

?

Is it possible to instruct Pandoc to use the tabular environment instead of longtable?  Otherwise, what is going wrong here?

And now you know why we always ask for full minimal examples. What is in your preamble here? \arraybackslash comes from the array package. Is is loaded?

There is no preamble, that is all that Pandoc produces.

You can use the -s option to generate a complete tex file

Then how are you using Table.tex? If it has that contents it cannot be copmpiled on its own, and if you did you're get a different error. So there is something you are not showing us.

If you used that as a complete document you would get errors before the one shown, longtable not defined for example

@daleif I am inserting that LaTeX table into a LaTeX template from a journal. The question is how can I know which packages are required by Pandoc in this circumstance.
